# HTML Div tags not working to assign separate divs to images

Tags: html

I have this image

[image]

The plan is to set the Linkedin icon below each yellow image in centre. Here is the Code:

```
<div class="contentEditableContainer contentGmapEditable" style="min-height: 0px;">

    <div class="contentEditable">   

<img data-default="placeholder" src="images/placeholder_2.jpg" width="75" style="padding:2px;border:1px solid #dbdeec;border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;">
<img data-default="placeholder" src="images/placeholder_2.jpg" width="75" style="padding:2px;border:1px solid #dbdeec;border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;">
<img data-default="placeholder" src="images/placeholder_2.jpg" width="75" style="padding:2px;border:1px solid #dbdeec;border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;">
<img data-default="placeholder" src="images/placeholder_2.jpg" width="75" style="padding:2px;border:1px solid #dbdeec;border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;">
<img data-default="placeholder" src="images/placeholder_2.jpg" width="75" style="padding:2px;border:1px solid #dbdeec;border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;">
<img data-default="placeholder" src="images/placeholder_2.jpg" width="75" style="padding:2px;border:1px solid #dbdeec;border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;">
<br>
<img  data-default="placeholder" src="images/linkedin.png" width="35" style="padding:2px;border:1px solid #dbdeec;border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;">
<img data-default="placeholder" src="images/linkedin.png" width="35" style="padding:2px;border:1px solid #dbdeec;border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;">
<img data-default="placeholder" src="images/linkedin.png" width="35" style="padding:2px;border:1px solid #dbdeec;border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;">
<img data-default="placeholder" src="images/linkedin.png" width="35" style="padding:2px;border:1px solid #dbdeec;border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;">
<img data-default="placeholder" src="images/linkedin.png" width="35" style="padding:2px;border:1px solid #dbdeec;border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;">
<img data-default="placeholder" src="images/linkedin.png" width="35" style="padding:2px;border:1px solid #dbdeec;border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;">
<img data-default="placeholder" src="images/linkedin.png" width="35" style="padding:2px;border:1px solid #dbdeec;border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;">                                                                             </div>                                                                                      </div>
```

The problem is, I have tried creating seperate divisions for these, like:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-2">
    <img data-default="placeholder" src="images/placeholder_2.jpg" width="75" style="padding:2px;border:1px solid #dbdeec;border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;">
                                                    <br>
<img  data-default="placeholder" src="images/linkedin.png" width="35" style="padding:2px;border:1px solid #dbdeec;border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;">
                                                </div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <img data-default="placeholder" src="images/placeholder_2.jpg" width="75" style="padding:2px;border:1px solid #dbdeec;border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;">
                                                    <br>
<img  data-default="placeholder" src="images/linkedin.png" width="35" style="padding:2px;border:1px solid #dbdeec;border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;">
                                                </div>
                                                </div>
```

In my thinking it should create separate divs for both images and the `<br>` should allow linkedin icon to be below the yellow one. It doesn't work, it rather creates like this:

[image]

am i missing something?

Comment: if you are planning to use bootstrap then you should create two rows one row will contain linkedin images and other will contain yellow images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it something like this

```css
.d1{
  float:left;
}
.d2{
  float:right;
}
.li{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-2 d1">
    <img data-default="placeholder" src="images/placeholder_2.jpg" width="75" style="padding:2px;border:1px solid #dbdeec;border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;">
                                                    <br>
      <div class="li">
<img  data-default="placeholder" src="images/linkedin.png" width="35" style="padding:2px;border:1px solid #dbdeec;border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px; text-align:center;">
        </div>
                                                </div>
<div class="col-md-2 d1">
    <img data-default="placeholder" src="images/placeholder_2.jpg" width="75" style="padding:2px;border:1px solid #dbdeec;border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;">
                                                    <br>
<div class="li">
<img  data-default="placeholder" src="images/linkedin.png" width="35" style="padding:2px;border:1px solid #dbdeec;border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px; text-align:center;">
        </div>
                                                </div>
<div class="col-md-2 d1">
    <img data-default="placeholder" src="images/placeholder_2.jpg" width="75" style="padding:2px;border:1px solid #dbdeec;border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;">
                                                    <br>
<div class="li">
<img  data-default="placeholder" src="images/linkedin.png" width="35" style="padding:2px;border:1px solid #dbdeec;border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px; text-align:center;">
        </div>
                                                </div>
<div class="col-md-2 d2">
    <img data-default="placeholder" src="images/placeholder_2.jpg" width="75" style="padding:2px;border:1px solid #dbdeec;border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;">
                                                    <br>
<div class="li">
<img  data-default="placeholder" src="images/linkedin.png" width="35" style="padding:2px;border:1px solid #dbdeec;border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px; text-align:center;">
        </div>
                                                </div>                     
 <div class="col-md-2 d2">
    <img data-default="placeholder" src="images/placeholder_2.jpg" width="75" style="padding:2px;border:1px solid #dbdeec;border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;">
                                                    <br>
<div class="li">
<img  data-default="placeholder" src="images/linkedin.png" width="35" style="padding:2px;border:1px solid #dbdeec;border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px; text-align:center;">
        </div>
                                                </div>
<div class="col-md-2 d2">
    <img data-default="placeholder" src="images/placeholder_2.jpg" width="75" style="padding:2px;border:1px solid #dbdeec;border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;">
                                                    <br>
<div class="li">
<img  data-default="placeholder" src="images/linkedin.png" width="35" style="padding:2px;border:1px solid #dbdeec;border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px; text-align:center;">
        </div>
                                                </div>                                                
                                                </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

So, I have put the top image in one row with 2 columns in each and the linked in image in another row, also with 2 columns.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row text-center">
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/75x75" alt="">
  </div>
 <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/75x75" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/75x75" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/75x75" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/75x75" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/75x75" alt="">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row text-center">
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">

    <img src="http://placehold.it/35x35" alt="">
  </div>
 <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">

    <img src="http://placehold.it/35x35" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">

    <img src="http://placehold.it/35x35" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">

    <img src="http://placehold.it/35x35" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">

    <img src="http://placehold.it/35x35" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">

    <img src="http://placehold.it/35x35" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

You would need to put your own images in there, this is just placeholders. Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

try to align images at center and use `display:inline-block;` OR `float:left` to left align `div`,

```
<div class="col-md-12" style="display:inline-block;">
    <div class="col-md-2" style="text-align: center;">
        <img data-default="placeholder" src="images/placeholder_2.jpg" width="75" style="padding:2px;border:1px solid #dbdeec;border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;">
        <br>
        <img  data-default="placeholder" src="images/linkedin.png" width="35" style="padding:2px;border:1px solid #dbdeec;border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2" style="text-align: center;">
        <img data-default="placeholder" src="images/placeholder_2.jpg" width="75" style="padding:2px;border:1px solid #dbdeec;border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;">
        <br>
        <img  data-default="placeholder" src="images/linkedin.png" width="35" style="padding:2px;border:1px solid #dbdeec;border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;">
    </div>
</div>
```